# ajax help calling js function in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="../play.js">player_update();    creature_update();</script>';
```

I am trying to make these two scripts run when the data from my ajax files echo it to the screen. any help?

Ex:  index.php sends data to .js file then js file sends the information to the servers php file which then returns the above script and runs the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script element with a `src` will ignore the body of the element completely.

If you want two scripts, then have them in two script elements.

```
<script src="../play.js"></script>
<script>
player_update();
creature_update();
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that it had to be 2 separate script tags. Thank you!